# Get Checked count in dynamic check boxes JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I'm using following code to design my screen dynamically according to the DB data.

```
function RefillUI(data) {
var html = "";
$.each(data,
    function (i, item) {
        $('#patientName').html(item.PatientName);
        html += "<div class='col-md-3'> <div class='card'><div class='card_header'><h5>" +
            item.DrugName +
            "</h5></div><div class='card_body'>" +
            "<div class='col-md-12'></div><ul class='col-md-6'><li class='bold'>Ref #</li><li class='bold'>" +
            item.ReferenceNo +
            "</li>" +
            "</ul><ul class='col-md-6'><li class='center'>Refills</li><li class='fill'>1</li></ul>" +
            "<table class='table table-bordered table-inverse'><tbody><tr><th>Prescriber</th><td>" +
            item.PatientName +
            "</td>" +
            "</tr><tr><th>Last filled</th><td>Nov 14 2014</td></tr><tr><th>Next fill</th><td>Oct 16 2016</td></tr>" +
            "<tr><th>Qty</th><td>" +
            item.LastRefillQty +
            "</td></tr><tr><th>Last Filled Dispensory</th><td>" +
            item.LastRefillDispensory +
            "</td></tr></tbody></table><form action='' class='cta center bold'>" +
            "<label><input name='refill' type='checkbox' value='refill'>Refill</label></form></div></div></div>";
    });


$('#refillcards').html(html);
```

}

Now I want to check how many check boxes are checked when click a button. How can I do this?

Comment: Radio buttons should not be checked more than one at a time. Did you mean a check box, or forgot a button group?

Comment: Yes. Check boxes.

Answer (score 0):

I know only answer in pure Javascript:

First, put this declaration at the top:

```
checkboxes = []; // No `var', it's global
```

This will initialize the stuff

```
function
init (n)
{
  // n is the number of check boxes
  checkboxes[0] = document.getElementById ('some-id');
  checkboxes[1] = document.getElementById ('other-id');
  // ...
  checkboxes[n - 1] = document.getElementById ('different-id');
}
```

To check selection for a particular check box, do:

```
function
checkSelect (n)
{
  if (n >= checkboxes.length)
    {
      throw "Index out of bounds: " + n;
    }
  return checkboxes[n].value;
}
```

Then, count all of then

```
function
count ()
{
  var ret = 0;
  for (var n = 0; n < checkboxes.length; n++)
    {
      if (checkSelect (n))
        {
          ret = ret + 1;
        }
    }
  return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var n = $( "input:checked" ).length;
```

you can replace input with a better selector if you want.